# Match a string to an enum name

Tags: java, testing, matcher, hamcrest

Is there any clean way of testing that a given String matches an enum name?

Right now I get

```
Expected: is <SUNDAY>
Actual: SUNDAY
```

I want to avoid having to add `.name()` to each check

```
assertThat("SUNDAY", is(SUNDAY.name()))
```

Something as

```
assertThat("SUNDAY", isEnum(SUNDAY))
```

I'm not asking how to write my own `Matcher`, I'm asking if there is already something built, which I can't seem to find.

Comment: Afaik, there isn't an existing matcher. AssertJ has, afaik, also no such matcher.

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**

You can use `Enum.valueOf(DAYS.class, "Sunday")`. I just named your enum `DAYS` because I don't know its name. This is what `Enum.valueOf` does:

> Returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the
>   specified name.  The name must match exactly an identifier used
>   to declare an enum constant in this type.  (Extraneous whitespace
>   characters are not permitted.)

In other words, in case there exists such enum value, you will get an enum instance, otherwise you will get an exception. So you can just assert the result and check whether you get a value or an exception gets thrown.

**Option 2**

You can create a `HashSet` as follows:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
for (final DAYS day : EnumSet.allOf(DAYS.class)) {
  set.add(day.name());
}
```

And just check whether the set `contains` the specific day:

```
assertTrue(set.contains("SUNDAY")); //Hope I'm using the assertion syntax right. Haven't used this framework before.
```

Comment: `Enum.valueOf` never returns `null`, it throws a `IllegalArgumentException` instead

Comment: Well, that's correct, but how is `assertThat(valueOf(Days.class, "SUNDAY"), is(SUNDAY))` cleaner than `assertThat("SUNDAY", is(SUNDAY.name()))`?

Comment: You don't need to add the name method as you mentioned, you don't need to write anything new and I assumed you don't know ahead which values would you get as input or which values exist in the enum. In this solution, you're totally flexible on that. Also - check the 2nd option I added, maybe it's more to your needs.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but option 2 won't work either. I would need to create that `Set` for every enum that I want to test and make it available to all test classes. Plus, that _contain_ naming is somehow misleading and collides with the existing `containsxxx` Matchers. I think that Floriant's comment is pretty much the answer to my question.

Comment: Option 2: **1:** use `assertTrue` instead of `assertThat` because assertTrue works on a simple boolean operator instead of an object and matcher. **2:** You can better use `name()` instead of `toString()` as the toString is commonly used to prove a human readable name for the enum

Comment: @Ferrybig - Thanks for you comment. Fixed accordingly.